# Serialize multiple data from database of same column

Tags: php, database, serialization

I'm new to PHP and using serialized data,

I have a Database which has a 2 tables, user & character.
characterId has a relation with userId.

An user has 2 characters, so I wanted to get the data with the following code:

```
public static function getCharacter() {
        $mysqli = Controller_Core_Config::getDB();
        if ($mysqli != null) {
            $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `character` WHERE `userId`='" . $user->getId() . "'";
            $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);

            if ($result !== FALSE && $result -> num_rows > 0) {
                $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION["character"] = serialize(new Model_Game_User(
                    $row['characterId'], 
                    $row['characterName'], 
                    $row['userId'], 
                    $row['level']
                    ));
            } else {
                echo "You have no characters.";
            }
        }
    }
```

And If I wanted to show the data I use the following code:

```
//some code
$character = unserialize($_SESSION["character"]);
$output .= $character->getCharacterName() . "<br>";
//some code
```

My problem is, that when I var_dump the ($_SESSION["character"])
I get only 1 character:

> string(202) "O:15:"Model_Game_User":4:{s:28:"Model_Game_UsercharacterId";s:1:"3";s:30:"Model_Game_UsercharacterName";s:9:"adminious";s:23:"Model_Game_UseruserId";s:1:"2";s:22:"Model_Game_Userlevel";s:1:"3";}"

And my question is, is it possible to have multiple 'characters' in serialized data?

Comment: Why would you want to serialize data at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping over your results. You are just adding the first result found into the session

You would need something like this to replace you `if` block:

```
if ($result !== FALSE && $result -> num_rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION["character"][] = array();
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION["character"][] = serialize(new Model_Game_User(
            $row['characterId'], 
            $row['characterName'], 
            $row['userId'], 
            $row['level']
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer but with the extra [] it gives me to following error: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: First off the error is because you need to initialize the `$_SESSION["character"]` as an array with `$_SESSION["character"] = array();` before you loop over your results, but re-reading your question it appears you aren't even looping over the results so are only ever loading the first character found into the session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will figure out to put this in a loop and see the results, otherwise I have to use an other method. thanks again for your help.

Comment: See my re-written answer, it should get you what you are after